# TextField: helperText spanning multiple lines

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have `TextField` with a `helperText`. I want to make the `helperText` span multiple lines. For that I needs some kind of line break. Material-UI renders `<p>{ helperText }</p>`. Since in html line breaks in paragraphs are given by `<br/>` I tried to add that to my text. This however just adds the `<br/>` into the text. I also tried defining the `helperText` outside the component, once with the `<br/>` and once with `\n`. But that didn't work either.

How do I properly add a line break into the `helperText`?

Example of my code:

```js
<TextField
    name={"help message"}
    value={data_field.helper_text}
    onChange={(event) => handleDataChange("helper_text", event.target.value)}
    helperText={"The value will be shown be shown below the field, just like this text is.<br> This <br/> text should go in the second line."}
/>
```

Example of result:

[image]

Comment: you can set the width of <p> using CSS/JSS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`helperText` props can accept a `ReactNode`, so you can add a `<br/>` element to break into newline like this:

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  helperText={
    <>
      The value will be shown be shown below the field, just like this text
      is.
      <br />
      This
      <br /> text should go in the second line.
    </>
  }
  {...props}
/>
```

[image: Edit 67264236/textfield-helpertext-spanning-multiple-lines]

Another solution as suggested by [@Vaibhav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67264236/textfield-helpertext-spanning-multiple-lines/67264565#comment118893841_67264236) is to set a width on the element that contains `helperText`:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import MuiTextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const TextField = styled(MuiTextField)({
  '& .MuiFormHelperText-root': {
    width: 250,
  },
});
```

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  helperText="The value will be shown be shown below the field, just like this text is. This text should go in the second line."
  label="Outlined"
  variant="outlined"
/>
```

[image: Edit 67264236/textfield-helpertext-spanning-multiple-lines (forked)]

Comment: my Lord savior /\